# How can I time out an input/output redirection in Linux?

Tags: linux, file-io, pipe

I was wondering whether or not it is possible to time out an input/output redirection in Linux.

Meaning that I would like to redirect certain input/output to a file just for a time span of 2s for instance.

In a practical case, I am looking to cat the *tty0* to a file only during 2s

```
cat /dev/tty0 >> ~/uart.txt
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You're not looking to timeout the redirection, you're just looking for a way to timeout the `cat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most linux, you should have access to `timeout`:

```
timeout 2 cat /dev/tty >> ~/uart.txt
```

This will send a SIGTERM after 2 seconds.  If you want a different signal, use -s.  If you want to follow up with SIGKILL, use -k.  `man timeout` for details.